# DateTimePicker: Restrict time of day with

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker

I have a `DateTimePicker` that will restrict the user from selecting weekends, but I am not sure how to limit the picker to only certain hours of the day as well. I have tried using `.AddHours(12)` but that could put the time at 4-5am which is outside of the window I'm trying to adhere to.
I'm trying to limit the selection between 8a-4p local time.
Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
Private Sub DateTimePick_CloseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DateTimePick.ValueChanged
    If (DateTimePick.Value.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday) Or (DateTimePick.Value.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday) Then

        'Now just add the right amount of days to make it Monday
        Select Case DateTimePick.Value.DayOfWeek
            Case DayOfWeek.Saturday
                DateTimePick.Value = DateTimePick.Value.AddDays(2)
            Case DayOfWeek.Sunday
                DateTimePick.Value = DateTimePick.Value.AddDays(1)
        End Select

        MsgBox("We're sorry, we are not currently scheduling maintenance for Saturday or Sunday. The following Monday, " &
               DateTimePick.Value.ToShortDateString & ", has been selected.",
               MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Invalid selection")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Just handling that one event is inadequate because the drop-down calendar is not the only way to set the date. I'd suggest just letting them select whatever they want and then handling the `Validating` event for the whole lot.

Comment: That makes sense and I realize the users can manually enter a date/time. But where I'm stuck is on restricting the hours between 8a-4p local time Do you have a suggestion of a good way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to automatically move weekends to the next Monday and invalid times to the nearest valid time on the same day, handle the `Leave` event and do this:

```vb
Private Sub DateTimePicker1_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.Leave
    Dim dt = DateTimePicker1.Value

    Select Case dt.DayOfWeek
        Case DayOfWeek.Saturday
            dt = dt.AddDays(2)
        Case DayOfWeek.Sunday
            dt = dt.AddDays(1)
    End Select

    If dt.TimeOfDay < TimeSpan.FromHours(8) Then
        dt = dt.Date.AddHours(8)
    ElseIf dt.TimeOfDay > TimeSpan.FromHours(16) Then
        dt = dt.Date.AddHours(16)
    End If

    DateTimePicker1.Value = dt
End Sub
```

If you want to force the user to select a valid date and time themselves, handle the `Validating` event and do this:

```vb
Private Sub DateTimePicker1_Validating(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.Validating
    Dim dt = DateTimePicker1.Value

    If dt.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday OrElse
       dt.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday OrElse
       dt.TimeOfDay < TimeSpan.FromHours(8) OrElse
       dt.TimeOfDay > TimeSpan.FromHours(16) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please select a time between 8:00 AM and 4:00 PM on a weekday",
                        "Invalid Date/Time",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                        MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```